# react native unexpected token stylesheet

Tags: javascript, react-native

There is my code & the error below. I made some changes in the App.js file, & since then this issue has shown up. I had my router setup in this file originally, but then decided to move. I've tried other styles & it doesn't work either.

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Navigator } from 'react-native';
import { Fonts } from './src/utils/Fonts';

import Menu from './app/components/Menu';
import Page from './app/components/Page';
import Router from './app/components/Router';


export default class App extends React.Component {
   
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.fonts}>
        <Menu />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fonts: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 12,
    fontFamily: Fonts.Baloo
  },
});
```

**Error**

[image]

I had different styles & code on the Menu component before this issue & it worked fine, but now even when I make changes it doesn't go back to the original, just shows this same error.

**Menu.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
 Image,
 MenuItem,
 Font,
 View,
 TextInput,
 TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';


export default class Menu extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text
        style={styles.fonts}
        onPress={() => Actions.page()}>
        Navvi
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
});
```

Comment: Your Text component at `Menu.js` , using `styles.fonts` but there is no `fonts` defined in your style, only `container`

Comment: Component **Menu.js** is missing a closing curly bracket (_render_ function).

Answer (score 0):

I already commented it, but this is how your code should look like (in **Menu.js**):

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text
          style={styles.fonts}
          onPress={() => Actions.page()}
        >
          {"Navvi"}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```